# How can I extend a line from two points to the edges of the plot area using Core Plot?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-plot

I'm using Core Plot to graph linear equations.

I would like to be able to supply two different data points and have a line drawn between them, but also extrapolated beyond the points themselves so that the line extends all the way to the edges of the plot area.

For example, given a 20x20 plot area with the origin centered and points at -5,-5 and 5,5, the line (green below) would extend all the way from -10,10 to 10,10 (blue below).

[image]

Is this possible? Is the best option just to find the plot range (which will be different each time) and find two points that are outside of it? I'm not sure if this will work; I have user interaction enabled and I want to make sure that the user can't accidentally pan far enough that the line will end.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of finding two endpoints outside the plot range is what I'd do. If you've limited the scrolling range, just pick points at the limits of that range. If not, you'll need to monitor changes to the plot space ranges with a plot space delegate and update the plot as needed.